# Set Consistency Level on Cassandra on ideal_consistency_level

Tags: cassandra, nosql, consistency

I know I can set consistency levels from cqlsh or for a client. if setting consistency level on ideal_consistency_level on the cassandra.yaml, will it set the consistency level for both reads and writes? So I don't have to do it on using cqlsh or any client.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a default consistency level for Cassandra on the server side.

If you want, you can change the hard-coded default of the **cqlsh** client by editing your `cqlsh.py` file, look at the line:

```
self.consistency_level = cassandra.ConsistencyLevel.ONE
```

and set it appropriately.

For your **java driver**, the default is [one](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.4/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions.html#DEFAULT_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL).

**ideal_consistency_level** is **not** a default consistency level. It was introduced in Cassandra [4.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13289), which is not yet scheduled for release. You only have access to Cassandra 4.0 if you compile Cassandra yourself from the correct branch. You configure ideal_consistency_level in order to get an idea of how likely you could have achieved a higher write consistency level than the one you are currently using. If you configure it, you then have access to two additional [keyspace metrics](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#keyspace-metrics) that indicate the fail count, and ideal consistency latency.